# Как определить, нажатие кнопки во Flash средствами JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash

Если не менять ничего в коде Flash, как можно определить, что в нем была нажата кнопка? Ролик запускается в браузере так

```
swfobject.embedSWF(url, "flashContent", "100%", "100%", "11.1", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, swfObjCallback);
```

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Поделюсь ссылкой, которая, возможно, будет полезна: [JavaScript onclick event over Flash object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4180324/5275890)

Comment: у меня флеш игра, запущенная в браузере, в ней несколько кнопок, я хочу программно узнать была ли нажата одна из кнопок. Из статьи я понял наложить что то прозрачное на кнопку и перехватывать нажатие на этом объекте?